# How to assign value to an array in while loop in php from mysqli result to make a counter to filter another while loop?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, mysqli, default

How to assign value to an array in while loop in php from mysqli result to make a counter to filter another while loop??

I want to assign something like this for my counter variable:

```
$counter = [
    "6:00 Am" => 0,
    "8:00 Am" => 0,
    "10:00 Am" => 0
);
```

For this code:

```
//This is from transaction table
$stm2 = "SELECT tr_sched FROM transaction WHERE tr_date = CURRENT_DATE()";
$res2 = $conn->query($res2);
while($rows5 = $res2->fetch_assoc())
{
  //Not working
  $counter[] = array($rows5['tr_sched'] => 0);
}
```

So I can filter this another while loop if the schedule time is greater than to my limit variable, like this:

```
//This is from my schedule table
$stm = "SELECT sc_time FROM schedule GROUP BY sc_time";
$res = $conn->query($stm);
$counter = array();
while($row4 = $res4->fetch_assoc());
{
  //Note working
  if ($counter[$row4['sc_time']] >= $limit/*=10*/)
  {
    echo "<option disabled="">" . $row4['sc_time'] . "</option>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<option>" . $row4['sc_time'] . "</option>";
  }
}
```

The goal of all the codes above is to display all schedule time from schedule table as an option for **select element** and if the schedule time is already have a 10 records or greater than(limit variable) on my transaction table for today it will display as option but disable so it can't be selected by user.

Comment: `$counter[] = ` creates a new element under a numeric key. You don’t want the key to be determined automatically here, you want to explicitly specify it – `$counter[$row4['sc_time']]`. And then you don’t want to assign an array _to_ that, but just 0 directly.

Comment: @CBroe I have to use array on it because I'm going to use it as the counter for my another while loop

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? If you want an array of the form you shown us as what you need, then _do it like I told you_. If you need something else - then you need to give us a _proper_ explanation first of all. (What other while loop? Why does it need a counter?)

Comment: @CBroe I updated it for my whole problem.

Comment: So just do what I said then …  (with the different row variable, you changed that in between)

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry but I still not get it, I'm currently learning this php and web developing

Comment: You want the value of `$rows5['tr_sched']` to become the array key, so _use it_ in the place, where one specifies the array key: `$counter[$rows5['tr_sched']] = 0;`

Comment: (Assuming, `tr_sched` is actually the column containing your `6:00 Am`, `8:00 Am` etc. values.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `while` loop at all.

You can use array functions to populate the array with static values.

```
$stm2 = "SELECT tr_sched FROM transaction WHERE tr_date = CURRENT_DATE()";
$res2 = $conn->query($stm2);
// get values from a single column
$keys = array_column($res2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC), 'tr_sched');
// create an array with all values as 0 and keys from $keys
$counter = array_fill_keys($keys, 0);
```

Of course, don't reset the array later on with `$counter = array();`

If you want to loop anyway, then you can use a simple `foreach` loop.

```
$stm2 = "SELECT tr_sched FROM transaction WHERE tr_date = CURRENT_DATE()";
$res2 = $conn->query($stm2);
foreach($res2 as $rows5) {
    $counter[$rows5['tr_sched']] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps also `SELECT tr_sched, 0 counter` then `array_column($res2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC), 'counter', 'tr_sched')`

Comment: @mick please post that as an alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code the default `0` value in your SELECT clause, then fetch the entire payload of rows, then call `array_column()` with 3 parameters to reduce the 2d array to a flat associative array.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/Fp))

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT tr_sched,
       0 counter
FROM transaction
WHERE tr_date = CURRENT_DATE()
SQL;

var_export(
    array_column(
        $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC),
        'counter', // use this as new values
        'tr_sched' // use this as new keys
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '6:00 Am' => '0',
  '8:00 Am' => '0',
  '10:00 Am' => '0',
)
```